# How to test a method that is invoking methods of another class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to understand how to do unit testing with Mockito. 
All the cases that I found is when a class A depends on a class B, that is A has an attribute of type B. I understand well this case. But how to do the tests when A uses B without getting it as attribute.

Suppose I have this code:

```
import package.classB;
public class A
{
    public int methodA(classB b) 
    {
    int x= b.methodB();
    //do something with x and then return the result
    }
}
```

How can I test the methodA?  Do I need to use mocks in this case?

Comment: You can mock `b` and also define what value it returns when you call `b.methodB()` so you can get the expected result from `methodA` and pass the test.

Comment: http://site.mockito.org/

Comment: Rule of thumb: if class `B` is a simple dumb *Data Transfer Object* (DTO) do *not* mock it. If  class `B` (and especially `methodB()` contains *business logic* then mock it. But there is a "gray zone": if you consider class `A` and class `B` being a *unit* only together in combination and neither one is a unit of its own then you don't mock. But this is a rare case and for my experience.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this will turn into a philosophical debate, which it probably mostly is.

The answer is - it depends.

You can use a Mockito object, or you can just pass in a fully formed object as the argument.  There are up and downsides to both.

Let's assume that ClassB is just a simple POJO.  Something like a user record.  It has a userID and a name field, and you want to test methodA.  I would generally just create an instance of the user object and than pass that into the argument.

Your test might look like

```
public class TestA {

   public void testMethodA() {
     B b = new B();
     int expectedValue = 1000;
     A a = new A();
     assertEquals(expectedValue, a.methodA(b));
   }

}
```

The benefit of this is that you have a fully formed object B and you are testing with real data.  The downside of this that is that Object B can be extremely complex or take long to generate.  For example, Object B could be a database lookup.

If Object B needs to be mocked, it can be mocked with Mockito, and then you get lots of ways to work with it.  The simplest case would be a variation of above.

```
public class TestA {

   public void testMethodA() {
     B b = Mockito.mock(B.class);
     Mockito.when(b.methodB()).thenReturn(10);
     int expectedValue = 1000;
     A a = new A();
     assertEquals(expectedValue, a.methodA(b));
   }
}
```

The upside of this is that you don't worry about what happens in Object B.  All you care about is that methodB in Object B returns a 10.  You are just testing method A, which doesn't care that much about what Object B is doing.  This can be much faster.  The downside is that you are making assumptions about what Object A is doing with Object B.  If Object A decided that it needed another method from Object B in methodA, your test would fail.  It also might hide some of the implementation from Object B, which might become important in some cases.

Personally, I tend to try to mock as little as possible.  This makes the setup of the tests more complex and it takes longer to run each test, but the upside is that I'm testing the whole process up to method A, starting from root data.

But there is nothing wrong with mocking Object B.  Tests become simpler and possibly quicker, with the downside that you are making assumptions about object B.